# Better way to specifying arguments for multivariable function

Tags: functions

If I'm working with many dimensions the amount of variables I have to use may get out of hand. I wonder if there's a quicker way to write something like below for example:

```
f[{x1_, x2_, x3_, x4_, x5_, x6_, x7_}] := x1^2 + x2^2 + x3^2 + x4^2 + x5^2 + x6^2 + x7^2 < 1
```

Comment: I found multivariable functions irritating when I was first using Mathematica and teaching multivariable calculus. AFAIK, there is no natural way to compose functions and have `Derivative` work. For a while I would define two paradigms: `f[v_List] := f @@ v; f[x_, y_, z_] := {x y, x^2 + z^2, 2 - y z}` or whatever. This is not exactly what you're asking about, but I would advise not to define `f` as a function on a vector/`List` if you want to differentiate it.

Comment: `f = Norm[#] < 1 &` is nearly equivalent (is if all numbers are always real).

Comment: @MichaelE2 I hate how Wolfram chose to prioritize rows over columns. It causes so many problems. My Initialize notebook, which runs every time I open Mathematica, defines `DTranspose = {3, 1, 4, 2}`. Then I can do `A = Array[a, {2, 2}]; X = Array[x, {2, 2}]; B = Array[b, {2, 2}]; 
Transpose[D[A.X + X.B, {X}], DTranspose] // MatrixForm`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
f2[xs_] := Total[xs^2] < 1;
f2[{a, b, c}]
(* a^2 + b^2 + c^2 < 1 *)
```

Now, you might have just used that sum-the-squared expression as an example, so it may need to be more complicated than this. Generally, though, if your arguments have some structure and some relationship, you can work directly with those semantics rather than destructure everything.

Comment: I never know what to make of an OP's "something like below"....Just what patterns are valid inferences? What sort of generalizations are we supposed to show? (+1)

Comment: yep. And after reading your comment/answer, it may be that I was too simplistic.

Comment: It happens all the time (that the OP posts a simpler, more symmetric example subject to efficient short cuts than their actual use case). Of course, it's one of the great reasons for discussing your problems. You see it one way and are stuck; the other person sees it a different way. Between the two, you get a better picture and an increased chance at solution.

Answer (score 4):

If you are bothered by manually writing the pattern for `f` with many arguments of type $x_i$, you can make an auxiliary function:

```
SetAttributes[args, HoldFirst];
args[var_, n_] := 
 Pattern[#, _] & /@ 
  Table[Symbol[SymbolName[Unevaluated[var]] <> ToString[i]], {i, n}]

Clear[f]
f[args[x, 50]] := x1 + 5 x20 + x33^5

Definition[f]
(* f[{x1_, x2_, x3_, x4_, x5_, x6_, x7_, x8_, x9_, x10_, x11_, x12_, 
   x13_, x14_, x15_, x16_, x17_, x18_, x19_, x20_, x21_, x22_, x23_, 
   x24_, x25_, x26_, x27_, x28_, x29_, x30_, x31_, x32_, x33_, x34_, 
   x35_, x36_, x37_, x38_, x39_, x40_, x41_, x42_, x43_, x44_, x45_, 
   x46_, x47_, x48_, x49_, x50_}] := x1 + 5 x20 + x33^5 *)
```

Comment: In my experience this is more safe than the down values `x[i]` since the variables are atomic. There are drawbacks though, when contexts and attributes are involved. And one way to solve this is to use the `Evaluate In Place` shortcuts.

Comment: Might I suggest `args[var_String, n_] := Table[ToExpression[var <> ToString[i], StandardForm, Function[Null, Pattern[#, _], HoldAll]], {i, n}]`? Then `Clear[f];
x = 7;
f[args["x", 50]] := x1 + 5 x20 + x33^5` works as expected. (`SymbolName[var]` leaks the evaluation of `x` if `var` is `x`. Alternatively, try `SymbolName[Unevaluated@var]`, which is a simpler change from what you have.)

Comment: @MichaelE2, thanks! I was trying to avoid strings to make it shorter in the first place, so I'll take your suggestion with `Unevaluated` :)

Answer (score 2):

Similar to @lericr's:

```
f1 // ClearAll;
f1[v_?VectorQ] := v . v < 1

f1[{x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6, x7}]

(*  x1^2 + x2^2 + x3^2 + x4^2 + x5^2 + x6^2 + x7^2 < 1  *)
```

Following my own advice in a comment, plus taking advantage of Mma's obfuscatory strengths <s>and breaking `Derivative` at the same time (even if the `< 1` is removed)</s>(`Derivative` seems to work if `< 1` is removed; test code had a typo):

```
f2 // ClearAll;
call : f2[__] := Block[{f2 = List}, call . call < 1]

f2[x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6, x7]

(*  x1^2 + x2^2 + x3^2 + x4^2 + x5^2 + x6^2 + x7^2 < 1  *)
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way to handle the problem of lots of variables is to use arrays rather than separately naming all the elements. For example, you can name your seven variables:

```
X = Array[x, 7];
```

so that

```
X = {x[1], x[2], x[3], x[4], x[5], x[6], x[7]}
```

Then define your function in terms of X:

```
f[z_] := z . z < 1
```

Then invoking

```
f[X]
x[1]^2 + x[2]^2 + x[3]^2 + x[4]^2 + x[5]^2 + x[6]^2 + x[7]^2 < 1
```

Answer (score 1):

This answer is an expanded comment.

Global variables are not safe and can cause lots of confusions. However, in some situations, using global variables are more convenient and suitable than specifying all the variables in every definition of functions.

For example, suppose we have a single notebook serving as a one-way script to calculate some quantities, and there are lots of **pure** functions with tree-like dependencies.

```
f0[args___]:=...

f11[args___]:="codes with f0"
f12[args___]:="codes with f0"

f2[args___]:="codes with f0, f11, f12"
...
```

Then the common arguments of the functions are better treated as global variables, especially the number of common arguments is quite large, say 20 arguments.

- This makes the code more readable, and the pattern matching more efficient.
- It's better to protect the global symbols at the beginning like

```
reserveSymbol[symbol_Symbol] :=
    (
        Unprotect@symbol;
        ClearAll@symbol;
        symbol::usage = "This symbol has been cleared and reserved.";
        Protect@symbol;
    );
```

- To evaluate some global symbols at specific values it's better to use `/.` and `//.`.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using `Indexed` in this case, as it allows to work with both variables and explicit `List`s, and it works flawlessly with `D`/`Derivative` and other functions. Example:

```mathematica
(* utility to create a list of indexed variables *)
indexed[x_, to_Integer] := Table[Indexed[x, i], {i, to}]
indexed[x_, from_Integer, to_Integer] := Table[Indexed[x, i], {i, from, to}]

(* a couple functions defined with this convention *)
f[x_] := With[{xi = indexed[x, 5]}, xi.xi]
g[x_] := With[{x1 = Indexed[x, 1], x2 = Indexed[x, 2]}, x1 + x2]

(* all the following examples work as expected *)
D[f[x], Indexed[x, 3]]
Derivative[{0, 0, 1, 0, 0}][f][indexed[x, 5]]
Reduce[f[x] < 1]
Reduce[f[{x1, 0, x3, 0, x5}] < 1]
f[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}]
Minimize[{g[x], f[x] < 1}, x \[Element] Ball[{1, 0, 0, 0, 0}]]
```

The code

```mathematica
Derivative[{0, 0, 1, 0, 0}][f][x]
```

requires special treatment, because `Derivative` insists in using `Part` instead of `Indexed`. A possible workaround is

```mathematica
(Derivative[{0, 0, 1, 0, 0}][f] /. Part -> Indexed)[x]
```

The only thing I regret is that `Indexed` cannot be inserted in a notebook with two-dimensional layout the same way as `Subscript` can (using `Ctrl + -` or `Ctrl + _`). Unfortunately one has to type `Indexed` explicitly. Other than that, it's perfect.